# how to route arrow from right to down css

Tags: css

[image: arrow]

I just want to route a arrow **down**.

My **CSS:**

```
.arrow-admin{
    bottom: -130px;
    right: -240px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 18px solid #666;
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with css property `transform`. This property allows you to rotate, scale, move, skew, etc., elements.

```
.arrow-admin{
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg); /* mozilla */
   transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```